# Connecting two remote networks over internet

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for suggestions on how to connect two networks over internet to use with ROS. This is as an attempt to collaborate between two universities so anything that can avoid bureaucratic juggling with network permissions would be best.

We can open up a port for the rosmaster to communicate between the two networks and we are able to see a listing of topics and services remotely. But no data can be read from the topics. I assume this is because when trying to do `rostopic echo <topic>` a p2p connection fails due to other ports not being open?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228742/connecting-two-remote-networks-over-internet/) by [oramirez](https://answers.ros.org/users/26237/oramirez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StevenWong](https://answers.ros.org/users/123465/stevenwong/) on 2022-11-15**:
I have got the same problem, if you have solutions, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your problem is related to name resolution. As stated in [ROS Network Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup),
all the machines need full bi-directional connectivity, on all ports. Moreover they have to resolve the name of each other. But I do not know how to solve these issues. I am also interested in.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some possibilities to do this (like [ipsec tunnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) fi, or SSH tunneling), but success of any approach will depend on what kinds of traffic the firewalls on both university networks will allow. Using a third party 'in the middle' might make things easier, as all connections will be considered *outgoing* by both university networks then (no need to 'open up ports' for a server at one of the ends).

After setting up the actual connection, it might make sense to look into a multi-master setup in combination with throttling of some of the more 'verbose' topics (such as `tf`). Most of the times this is taken care of by the multi-master system though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1